# "jarsigner -tsa ..." leads to a jar that cannot be verified on java 6, while simply "jarsigner ..." is fine

Tags: java, pkcs#7, java-security

The company I work for distributes a part of its software as signed Java jar files. There is a requirement that the jar files must be "verifiable" on Java 6. There is a mechanism that reads the jar entries and fails when either a signature is wrong or absent for any entry. The code is (simplified):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.*;

public final class JarCheckSimple {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        check(new File("SuperAwesome.jar"));
    }

    private static void check(File file) throws IOException {
        JarFile jar = new JarFile(file);
        Manifest manifest = jar.getManifest();
        if (manifest == null) {
            throw new SecurityException("jar not signed " + jar);
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8096];
        Enumeration entries = jar.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry e = (JarEntry) entries.nextElement();
            if (!e.isDirectory() && !e.getName().startsWith("META-INF")) {
                InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(e);
                while (is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) != -1) { /* to be verified by VerifierStream */ }
                is.close();

                Certificate[] certs = e.getCertificates();
                if (certs == null || certs.length == 0) { /* Works on Java 8, fails on Java 6: (certs == null) is true there */
                    throw new SecurityException("unsigned entry " + e.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Recently our Release Engineering department has tried to change the signing process to enable signature timestamp support (this thing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/time-of-signing.html), and since then the check above started to fail on Java 6 (only) -- my question ultimately will be why, but I have to give some details first. Release Engineering claim they use all the same certificates and all, the only change is they added "-tsa http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp" to the jarsigner command they have.

I set the `-Djava.security.debug=jar` parameter for the code above and got this difference in the output (for jar files signed with and without timestamp, checked on Java 6 and Java 8):

Java 6, no timestamp (CERTIFICATE.RSA is under 4 KB here):

```
jar: beginEntry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
jar: done with meta!
jar: nothing to verify!
jar: beginEntry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
jar: beginEntry META-INF/CERTIFICATE.SF
jar: processEntry: processing block
jar: beginEntry META-INF/CERTIFICATE.RSA
jar: processEntry: processing block
jar: Signature Block Certificate: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=SuperCompany Ltd, OU=IT, O=SuperCompany Ltd, L=Rwanda, C=CH
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ...
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue May 29 02:00:00 CEST 2018,
               To: Sun Jun 28 01:59:59 CEST 2020]
  Issuer: CN=thawte SHA256 Code Signing CA, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US
  SerialNumber: [    ...]

Certificate Extensions: 8
...
```

So it looks like the certificate is found and parsed.

Java 8, with timestamp (CERTIFICATE.RSA is over 7 KB here):

```
jar: beginEntry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
jar: done with meta!
jar: nothing to verify!
jar: beginEntry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
jar: beginEntry META-INF/CERTIFICATE.SF
jar: processEntry: processing block
jar: beginEntry META-INF/CERTIFICATE.RSA
jar: processEntry: processing block
jar: Unsupported signer attribute: 1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47
jar:
jar: Detected signature timestamp (#885515941755655847907684100465949331954643356622) generated on Tue Jun 26 14:11:42 CEST 2018
jar:
jar: Signature Block Certificate: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=SuperCompany Ltd, OU=IT, O=SuperCompany Ltd, L=Rwanda, C=CH
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ...
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue May 29 02:00:00 CEST 2018,
               To: Sun Jun 28 01:59:59 CEST 2020]
  Issuer: CN=thawte SHA256 Code Signing CA, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US
  SerialNumber: [    ...]

Certificate Extensions: 8
...
```

Note the "warning" about "Unsupported signer attribute: 1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47"; but still, the certificate is parsed fine.

Now, the problem: Java 6, with timestamp (CERTIFICATE.RSA is over 7 KB here):

```
jar: beginEntry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
jar: beginEntry META-INF/CERTIFICATE.SF
jar: processEntry: processing block
jar: beginEntry META-INF/CERTIFICATE.RSA
jar: processEntry: processing block
jar: ignoring unsupported signer attribute: 1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47
jar: processEntry caught: sun.security.pkcs.ParsingException: Unable to parse the encoded bytes
jar: done with meta!
jar: nothing to verify!
...
```

So, Java can't parse some block, therefore it treats the whole jar as unsigned, therefore our check (above) fails: the JarEntry::getCertificates() returns null.
For the sake of completeness: running "jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs SuperAwesome.jar" prints everything fine for the jarsigner from JDK 8, and prints for each jar entry that it was simply "mentioned" (not signed) for JDK 6.

Debugging with some OpenJDK source code attached, I found that this is why Java 6 fails (`sun.security.pkcs.PKCS9Attribute#PKCS9Attribute(sun.security.util.DerValue)`):

```
    ...
    // get the oid
    ObjectIdentifier oid = val[0].getOID();
    index = indexOf(oid, PKCS9_OIDS, 1);
    if (index == -1) {
        if (debug != null) {
            debug.println("ignoring unsupported signer attribute: " + oid);
        }
        throw new ParsingException("Unsupported PKCS9 attribute: " + oid);
    }
    ...
```

While Java 8 passes fine:

```
    ...
    // get the oid
    oid = val[0].getOID();
    byte[] content = val[1].toByteArray();
    DerValue[] elems = new DerInputStream(content).getSet(1);

    index = indexOf(oid, PKCS9_OIDS, 1);
    if (index == -1) {
        if (debug != null) {
            debug.println("Unsupported signer attribute: " + oid);
        }
        value = content;
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Also, all logic in `sun.security.pkcs.PKCS9Attribute` is ready for this.index == -1, unlike in the Java 6 version. I can even modify this class to be more like in JDK 8, and then the test passes; the problem however is that I don't have control over the user's JDK.

It looks like my problem could be solved if the certificate didn't have this "1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47" oid present (the only info I could find on it is: [id-aa-signingCertificateV2](http://oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47)). I have to confess I know nothing about the whole process of signing (both in principle and how it's done by our Release Engineering -- it seems they obscure it on purpose), certificates etc.

Now, my questions are:

1. Am I right that the most straightforward way to fix this would be to get rid of this attribute "1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47"?
2. Is it possible to say having the information I provided what introduces it into the resulting certificate that ends up in the jar file? (That CERTIFICATE.RSA)
3. If not, could you hint me what my next steps could be in trying to track down or fix the problem? I am stuck.

I am on Windows 7, using Oracle JDK 6 update 45 and Oracle JDK 8 update 20.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The most straightforward way would be for them to stop using the `-tsa` option. Or raise the minimum JDK to Java 7. You'll do the latter at some point.

Comment: even jdk 7 reached "end of updates" stage in 2015.

Comment: Your jar verification code is flawed; ignoring all files in `META-INF` will cause it to ignore service provider-configuration files of [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) under `META-INF/services` and most importantly classes of [multi-release JAR files](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238). You should probably validate all files, even in `META-INF`, except the `MANIFEST.mf` and signature related files.